# Windows 7 x64 doesn't recognize Canon Rebel XT camera

Tags: usb, camera

When I plug my Canon Rebel XT into my Windows 7 x64 laptop via USB, I was expecting it to allow me to browse the photos on the CF card.  Instead, Win7 attempts to install a device driver and fails.  I see the camera as an unknown device in Device Manager.

There doesn't seem to be a driver for the [Rebel](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/windows_vista/cameras/eos_slr_camera_systems/digital_rebel_xt#ServiceAndSupport) XT for Win7 x64.

I know I can get a CF USB card reader and view the photos that way but anyone know how I can view the photos via USB cable connection to the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> change the setting in menu > the last icon > communication > change from PC to print/ptp and you will be able to communicate again with the camera

Found on this forum
http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7hardware/thread/9bbdc0f6-9c1b-4714-8a57-650ba12dce3e

Answer (score 0):

Install the software that came with the camera in XP compatible mode and see if that doesn't work.

Comment: I purchased the camera 4 years ago so I don't have the the software that came with the camera.  Even if I did, other than drivers, I'm reluctant to install vendor-ware unless it's absolutely required.

Comment: The software can be downloaded from the support page you linked.